# Unmount and then wrapper.mount() again does not work properly at Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Enzyme: 2.8.2
React: 15.5.4

If we do wrapper.unmount(), and then wrapper.mount(), the component is not mounted properly. I can see an empty console output after mounting again.

Simple plain example as follows

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.id}>
        {this.props.id}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const wrapper = mount(<Foo id="foo" />);

console.log("log before unmounting", wrapper.mount().debug()); //This logs the component properly

wrapper.unmount();

console.log("Log again after mounting", wrapper.mount().debug());//this logs empty component
```

Comment: I don't see in your example where you have unmounted and then mounted again. It seems to me like you're mounting and then unmounting.

Comment: in the last line where i do console.log i am mounting it again
_wrapper.mount()_